# Get column to display month name Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I set a column to display the name of the month instead of the whole date using the script?

The function can manually be performed by selecting `Format>Number>August` in the menu but I want to do this in code.

This is what I've tried but I can't seem to find what I'm supposed to put in as the "format condition":

```
function myFunction() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spr.getSheets()[0];
  var column = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  column.setNumberFormats("Month"); // I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be "Month" here, so what is it supposed to be?
}
```

Clarification; I want to set an entire column to change: `01/01/2015` to show `January`.

The error message I get on above code is "Cannot find method setNumberFormats(string)" and it's the same if i change `"Month"` to `"L"` or `"MM"`.

Comment: thanks for editing some typos, but there are a few left : getSheet() needs an S and setNumberFormats() has no S.

Comment: Sorry, missed that once since the code here is not the exact same one I use in my actual code. Actual code is not misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of typos in your script...(please be more careful when writing code and make use of autocomplete to check spelling : control+SPACE)

code goes like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spr.getSheets()[0];
  var column = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  column.setNumberFormat("MMMM"); // MMM for abbreviated month, MM for month number
}
```

Comment: I think a key was that I used the wrong version where I used `setNumberFormats` instead of the singular version. Thanks.